# How to know if checkbox is ticked in a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, checkbox

I have a `checkbox` in my `jsp` page as the following :

```
<div class="col-lg-8 ">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="approver" id="ck2" value="Approver">     Approver</label><hr/>                                                                                                                                                   
</div>
```

In my `servlet` I want to know if the value of the `checkbox` is `checked` or no. I have tried looking at the other threads but they don't seem to be working for me. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do `request.getParameter("approver")` if you get the value as null then its unchecked, else its checked if you get the valid value.

Whenever we submit checkbox without checking `request.getParameter()` returns null.